# error in react-native run-android

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

I am trying to run my app on the emulator
But where it's going to hang
And others do not
What is the problem?
[image]

http://uupload.ir/files/w7jt_hang.png

And after a few minutes this happens
http://uupload.ir/files/x5pw_v.jpg

Comment: It seems to be permission issue, try this  `npm install npm@latest-g` run command as admin

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command to re-install your packages and clean your cache `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`
It could take a couple minutes to run so be patient with it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by two ways as follows:
1] Please remove node_modules folder of your project and afterward you need to bypass all permission related issues by changing the prefix for npm. Please use below command to bypass all permissions:

```
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

Then use below commands:

```
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

2] You need to run your command prompt(cmd.exe) as administrator.(right click to 
    command prompt and run as administrator)
Then use below commands:

```
npm install
```